# Projectivity of $R[t]$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, modules, projective-module

I want to show that "if $R$ is a commutative ring and $P$ is a projective $R$-module, then $R[t] \otimes_R P$ is also a projective $R[t]$-module where $R[t]$ is a polynomial ring."
I tried it but I'm not sure if I did it correctly.  My attempt is below.
[image]
[image]

Thank you all.

${\bf Edit}$: From looking at some proof from Rotman's text, I modified it to make a much shorter argument.
Since $P$ is a projective $R$-module, we know $P$ is a direct summand of some free $R$-module i.e $\bigoplus_{i \in I} R \cong P \oplus N$.  Since tensoring preserve direct sum, we have
$$ \bigoplus_{i \in I} R[t] \cong R[t] \otimes_R \big(\bigoplus_{i \in I} R\big)  \cong (R[t] \otimes_R P) \oplus (R[t] \otimes_R N).$$
But this implies that $R[t] \otimes_R P$ is a projective $R[t]$-module.

Comment: It's correct, though it's not exactly $h:P\to A$ which is made an $R[t]$-linear map, after all we don't have any (compatible) $R[t]$-action given on $P$, but that's not needed. We use the $R$-linear map $h$ to construct the $R[t]$-linear $\bar h$.

Comment: @Berci Thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "I tried it but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. My attempt is below."

**Answer:** Note that if $\phi:A \rightarrow B$ is a map of unital commutative rings and if $P$ is a finite rank projective $A$-module with split surjection (split by $s$)

$$p: A^n \rightarrow P \rightarrow 0$$

you get canonically a split surjection $1\otimes p: B\otimes_A A^n \rightarrow B\otimes_A P \rightarrow 0$

split by $1\otimes s$. Hence $B\otimes_A P$ is a projective finite rank $B$-module.

**Example:** Your case follows with $B:=A[t]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   I see, so I just want to verify, $B$ is an $A$-module via the action $a \cdot b = \phi(a)b $ and we would have $B \otimes_A A^n \cong B^n$ which is a free $B$-module ? Also, I don't see why we need to assume $P$ is finite rank since wouldn't your proof work for any projective $A$-module P? The only change is we just have a surjection $\oplus_{i \in I} A \to P$ Thank you.

Comment: @Khoata - the proof holds for arbitrary projective modules. A surjection $p: \oplus_{i\in I}A \rightarrow P$ has a section $s$, and then a the maps $1\otimes p$ and $1\otimes s$ proves that $B\otimes_A P$ is a projective $B$-module. We get $1 \otimes p \circ 1 \otimes s = 1 \otimes (p \circ s)=1 \otimes I_P =I_{B\otimes_A P}$.